# Does Fixed Point theorem work on an integer to integer mapping?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fixed-point-theorems

I have an equation which I need to get its (least) fixed point for. Generally, we have:

```
x_{k+1} = f (x_{k})   # fixed point iteration
f: N -> N     # N is the set of natural numbers
```

Is it possible to use the same fixed point theorem to prove that:

1. The function admits at least one fixed point
2. Finding the fixed point is guaranteed via an iterative algorithm

if the domains are sets of integers, and if so is there a source in literature?

Note: The iterative algorithm just assumes an initial value for `x` and computes the next value until the values are equal.

If needed, the functions which I refer to come from worst case response time of scheduling non-preemptive fixed-priority tasks in a task set.

```
# ceil() is the ceiling function

# equation one
w = a + b(1 + ceil(w/c))
```

where `w` is the variable and `a`, `b`, `c` are constants.

The form of the equation is a dummified version from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281567091_Preemptive_and_Non-Preemptive_Real-Time_UniProcessor_Scheduling) of Theorem 15. But the form should suffice anyway.

Comment: what happens if $f(n) = n+1 \; ? \; \;$

Comment: There are many, many fixed point theorems. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm not sure why there are many or which ones you're referring to (?) I mean I want to be able prove if a fixed point of a certain function exists, i.e. For the equation f(x)=x, I want to see if there exists an x = x* such that f(x*)=x*. But the theorem is defined for closed interval in IR.

Comment: There are so many fixed point theorems because there are many, many different situations where maps can have fixed points, and conditions that can show such fixed points exist. And I am not the one who is referring to any specific fixed point theorem. THAT IS YOU. And I am requesting that you PLEASE say what fixed point theorem you are talking about, so the rest of us can know as well. STATE the theorem. Then we will know. Stop assuming that we also live in your head and can know what you are talking about without your bothering to tell us.

Comment: @PaulSinclair First of all: no need to be sassy about it. I'm not a Mathematician; nevertheless I did not know many existed like Banach, Brouwer, etc.  Unsurprisingly, "Fixed point Theorem" can be seen [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPointTheorem.html). To dive a bit deeper, I am mainly referring as well to the fixed point iteration as described [in these notes](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture9.pdf). The problem is that there it's assumed the ft is defined on a closed interval. SO my question is, do we have similar theorems for functions defined on IN.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I think your comment _was_ somewhat harshly formulated: I suspect that Mo Kanj’s native language is not English, and that this has led them to a formulation that sounds as though they have a specific theorem in mind, in particular the use of the definite article ‘_the_’. But they do seem rather confused about the maths as well:(